# How to add a bottom border to a label as a sublayer in swift?

Tags: swift2

I am trying to insert a colored line under one of my labels :

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 40))
label.text = items[index - 1]
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
label.textAlignment = .Center
label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 15)
label.textColor = index == 1 ? selectedLabelColor : unselectedLabelColor
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

var sublayer = label.layer;
sublayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, label.frame.width, 1);
sublayer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
sublayer.borderWidth = 1;
self.layer.insertSublayer(sublayer, atIndex: 0)

self.addSubview(label)
```

How can I set the frame properly so that there is a colored line under my label ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using a uiview :

```
let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,
                      self.frame.height - 3,
                      label.frame.width,
                      3.0))

lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.addSubview(lineView)
```

Works really well.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3:

```
let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.height - 3, width: frame.width, height: 3.0))
lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
self.addSubview(lineView)
```